# WebDriver test jumps between fields when typing

Tags: laravel, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, laravel-dusk

In my Laravel 5.7 project, I'm using Dusk browser testing to assert that a form submission is handled properly.

But the test randomly switches between fields when trying to type out the values.

My code is:

```
$browser->visit(self::PATH)
    ->waitFor(self::HIDDEN_FORM, 1)// Wait a maximum of one second for the selector...                    
    ->type(self::NAME_FIELD, 'John Doe')
    ->type(self::EMAIL_FIELD, 'example@example.com');
```

But the test randomly errors out (because of the following invalid input) and generates a screenshot, and the screenshot contains variations of:

```
Name: John Doeple@example.com
Email: exam
```

Or:

```
Name: John Doeple.com
Email: example@exam
```

Or:

```
Name: John Doeexample@example.com
Email:
```

And many other random variations of the text not being typed continuously in the correct fields.

(Can you see that while it was typing the Email field, the cursor jumped back to the Name field?)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does your site use some kind of JavaScript form validation?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes. And that's what this test is trying to test. Hmm. I see that I have a handler on `'keydown change'` of the `#email` field. But I'm still not seeing how this test behaves so RANDOMLY. I would think it would be deterministic. Sometimes it passes, but often it jumps between fields while typing.

Comment: Unfortunately, browser testing isn't always an exact science. There was a similar case a while ago: We could fix it by typing each character separately using `$browser->keys()` and adding a small pause after each one (e.g. 100 milliseconds).

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Interesting. Currently I've wrapped these problematic tests in `retry(6, function() {...` which doesn't feel good either.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I tried `public function typeSlowly($browser, $field, $value) { foreach (str_split($value) as $char) { $browser->type($field, $char) ->pause(100); } }` but each field ends up containing only the last char of `$value` because apparently the loop is overwriting the field value every time. I must have misinterpreted what you were suggesting? Thanks.

Comment: Ahh I need to use `keys` instead of `type`. It seems to be working now.

Comment: You can also use `append()`. Then you can still use `$field` instead of a CSS selector.